# is using the same instance of udpclient on different threads while only receiving/sending thread safe?

Tags: c#, multithreading, sockets, udpclient

im trying to implement a quick thread safe socket for udp. for this Im creating a while true loop for both send and receive that will constantly send/receive information as needed.

I created this in a few minutes just for a rough idea of how it'll work. this is from the belief (that I'm not sure of) that send and receive methods do not affect each other or the object.

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Net.Sockets;
    using System.Threading;
    using System.Collections.Concurrent;
    
    
    namespace ConsoleApp1
    {
        class ThreadSafeSocket
        {
            private UdpClient udpclient;
            private ConcurrentQueue<SendInfo> sendData;
            private SendInfo data;
            private object recieveLock;
            private int port;
            public ThreadSafeSocket(int port)
            {
                this.udpclient = new UdpClient(port);
                this.sendData = new ConcurrentQueue<SendInfo>();
                this.port = port;
                Thread receiveThread = new Thread(RecieveLoop);
                Thread sendThread = new Thread(SendLoop);
                receiveThread.Start();
                sendThread.Start();
            }
    
            public void Send(SendInfo data)
            {
                sendData.Enqueue(data);
            }
            public SendInfo Receive()
            {
                lock(recieveLock)
                {
                    byte[] receivedata = new byte[data.Data.Length];
                    Array.Copy(receivedata, data.Data, data.Data.Length);
                    IPEndPoint point = new IPEndPoint(data.Point.Address, data.Point.Port);
                    return new SendInfo(receivedata, point);
                }
            }
            private void SendLoop()
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    if (sendData.TryDequeue(out SendInfo result))
                    {
                        udpclient.Send(result.Data, result.Data.Length,this.data.Point);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Thread.Sleep(1);
                    }
                }
            }
            private void RecieveLoop()
            {
                while(true)
                {
                    IPEndPoint point = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, this.port);
                    byte[] data = this.udpclient.Receive(ref point);
                    lock(recieveLock)
                    {
                        this.data = new SendInfo(data, point);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

}
```

sendinfo consists of a byte array called data, and an ipendpoint called point.

I've heard that thread safety is very hard to test so if the idea itself is wrong id asked before testing. thanks in advance.

Comment: You shouldn't mix async with Thread. You're also not receiving asynchronously (updclient.Receive instead of udpclient.ReceiveAsync).

Comment: No, that is not a correct implementation. For several reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Well I got my answer, sockets by themselves already can't receive and send at the same time most likely so this implementation is wrong. It's better instead to just look an instance of udpClient and not the methods.